# Kernel of a homomorphism is closed under the inverse mapping

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G,G'$ be two groups and $f:G \rightarrow G'$ a group homomorphism. How can we show that $H = \ker(f)$ is closed under the inverse mapping?

Actually, I could not understand the statement completely. Any hint would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you mean that to prove $a,b\in \ker f \implies ab \in \ker f$?

Comment: This statement is from Lang's Algebra. Unfortunately, it is something different than the implication you wrote.

Comment: Can you give a page reference for Lang? There does seem to be some ambiguity about what you're asking as noted by @AlanWang.

Comment: It is on 11st page, 3rd edition.

Comment: Right, so you are trying to prove, essentially, that $a\in\ker f\Rightarrow a^{-1}\in\ker f.$

In other words, that $\ker f$ is closed under inverses. Basically, Lang is checking the group axioms to show that $\ker f$ is a group.

Comment: So I must check $a \in ker f \implies a^{-1} \in ker f$. Then what is next to be checked?

Comment: As a personal aside, and some people may feel differently, I don't think that Lang is particularly helpful if you are attempting to independently learn algebra for the first time. There are some great undergraduate-level books that give much more "friendly" introductions to the topic.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not my first time but I still do not know what to do in this question. I actually worked on Fraleigh before Lang.

Comment: On page 9, about halfway down, Lang covers what is required for a subset of a group $G$ to be a sub**group**. The axioms to check are (a) containment of the identity element; (b) closure under the group operation; and (c) closure under inverses. You are checking part (c) right now.

Comment: So I pick $a^-1$ then show that $a$ is in the kernel? That makes no sense .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you seem to still be seeking the answer, I will write up an answer for you closely following Lang:

Let $G, G'$ be groups and $f:G\to G'$ be a group homomorphism.

**Proposition**: $a\in\ker f\Rightarrow a^{-1}\in\ker f$.

**Proof**: Let $a\in \ker f$ and $e\in G$ and $e'\in G'$ be the identity elements (or *units*) in their respective groups. By the definition of $\ker f$, we know $f(a)=e'$ and by the definition of a group homomorphism, we know that $f(e)=e'$.

Now compute
$$e'=f(e)=f(a\cdot a^{-1})=f(a)f(a^{-1})=e'\cdot f(a^{-1})=f(a^{-1}).$$

Therefore $f(a^{-1})=e'$, so $a^{-1}\in\ker f$, as desired.

---

From here, you would have to prove the following two statements to be able to conclude $\ker f\le G$:

1. $a,b\in\ker f\Rightarrow ab\in\ker f$
2. $e\in\ker f$.

Comment: Should not we show that $H=ker f$, $H^{-1} \subseteq H$?

Comment: So the first statement, $H=\ker f$, is basically a statement about naming. It's just saying "Let $H$ be the set $\ker f$." Nothing to prove there. The second statement, $H^{-1}\subseteq H$ is what we proved above. :) Notice we took the inverse of something in $H$ and showed it was also in $H$.

Comment: So why $H^{-1} \subseteq H$ is not enough? We are asked to show that it is closed under inverse image, but then we check 2 more: $HH \subseteq H$ and $1 \in H$.

Comment: Well, you only asked for clarification of Lang's proof for closure under inverses. I was just adding that if you wanted to finish the rest of the proof that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, you would have to prove the other two facts as well. That is what Lang intended the reader to do.